# ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error - Mac OS X and R

Tags: macos, r, fonts, osx-mountain-lion

I recently installed R on a new Macbook Pro running Mountain Lion. When trying to plot data, I get a slew of ATSFontGetFileReference errors, and text doesn't render (though chart elements do):

```
> plot(study$outcome, study$predictor)
Jan 21 10:55:57 tatou.local R[35029] <Error>: ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error -50.
Jan 21 10:55:57 tatou.local R[35029] <Error>: ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error -50.
Jan 21 10:55:57 tatou.local R[35029] <Error>: ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error -50.
Jan 21 10:55:57 tatou.local R[35029] <Error>: ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error -50.
...
```

It seems like more of an OS X issue than R, since a little Googling has turned up similar errors for PDF renderers, etc. But I can't seem to find a solution...

All my fonts as well as R appear to be installed for use system-wide. Ideas?

Comment: Never used `R` before: can you give the details on the versions of the framework and GUI (also the 64bit or 32 bit) you're using? Do you have any custom font settings in the GUI (I can't even do that, as `R 2.15.2 GUI 1.53 Leopard build 64-bit (6335)` gets uncaught exception when trying to choose a font.

Comment: No custom font settings I'm aware of. However, I was running R64.app before, and after posting this I tried R.app, which appears to work.

Comment: The version that is OK: R 2.15.2 GUI 1.53 Leopard build 32-bit (6335)
The error version: R 2.15.2 GUI 1.53 Leopard build 64-bit (6335)

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this...?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error using RStudio on OSX 10.7.5. I saved my workspace and then quit RStudio. Upon opening it back up and loading my saved workspace, I ran the plot(x,y) command and there was no longer an error, with the text being displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your font situation exactly, but I just fixed this issue on mine. I have a mac, and helvetica is automatically installed as a .dfont file. I had downloaded a helvetica.ttf file and put it in 'mac_hd/libary/fonts'. Once I deleted this and restarted R I haven't had the problem. My error was verbatim ' ATSFontGetPostScriptName failed: error -984. ' (I included that to help with google results)